# Cordova GeoLocation not applying lat long to json get

Tags: json, cordova, ionic-framework, geolocation, ngcordova

I'm using the Cordova Geolocation plugin to get the users lat and long data. The intention is use that lat and long and apply it to an api call I'm making to Breezometer. Unfortunately my code is is not working correctly. Can someone let me know what im missing here:

```
.controller('GeoCtrl', function($cordovaGeolocation, $scope, $http) {
var posOptions = {timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: false};
$cordovaGeolocation
  .getCurrentPosition(posOptions)
  .then(function (position) {
    var lat  = position.coords.latitude
    var long = position.coords.longitude

    $scope.result = "";
    $http.get('https://api.breezometer.com/baqi/?lat='+ lat + 'lon=-' + long + '&key=c329a5b015f442748e088cfd13726267')
      .success(function(data, status, headers,config){
        console.log('data success');
        console.log(data); // for browser console
        $scope.result = data; // for UI
      })
      .error(function(data, status, headers,config){
        console.log('data error');
      })
      .then(function(result){
        things = result.data;
      });


  }, function(err) {
    // error
  });


var watchOptions = {
  frequency : 1000,
  timeout : 3000,
  enableHighAccuracy: false // may cause errors if true
};

var watch = $cordovaGeolocation.watchPosition(watchOptions);
watch.then(
  null,
  function(err) {
    // error
  },
  function(position) {
    var lat  = position.coords.latitude
    var long = position.coords.longitude
});


watch.clearWatch();
// OR
$cordovaGeolocation.clearWatch(watch)
  .then(function(result) {
    // success
    }, function (error) {
    // error
  });
```

})

Answer (score 0):

The url for your `http` request is wrong.

Try the following,

`$http.get(https://api.breezometer.com/baqi/?lat='+ lat + '&lon='+ long +'&key='+ key)`

You have miised `&` in between lat and lon. And lon need not be prefixed with `-`

Example:
`https://api.breezometer.com/baqi/?lat=13.082680199999999&lon=80.2707184&key=c329a5b015f442748e088cfd13726267`

Click [here](https://api.breezometer.com/baqi/?lat=13.082680199999999&lon=80.2707184&key=c329a5b015f442748e088cfd13726267) to view the results.